# Academic course repeats every week and every term. Succinct terminology to tell one from the other?

Tags: academia

I am participating in an academic course that is multiple weeks long (the course spans a full term / a full semester). In some years, the whole course is offered multiple times a year (every term / every semester), in some years it is not. Successful completion of the course is a small part of completing a degree program.

I am looking for terminology to use in place of the **bold** words below.

> Two things that are repeating:
>
> - two times per week, a **date**/**session**/**...** of the course is taking place
> - every third term, a new **iteration**/**run**/**...** of the course is taking place

Ideally, the terminology should be both succinct and unambiguous. For example, I'd like to be understood as not being able to attend a **session** as opposed to not being able to attend an entire **iteration**.

I am sure such terminology already exists, particularly in an academic setting, but without knowing what words to look for I am stumped.

Comment: (a) a class /// you'd say 'a new course takes place' or 'the course is repeated each term'.

Comment: For a whole run of the course, I'd expect a program/prospectus/calendar to say something like "The course is offered twice yearly, sessions start in January and September" or "the course starts in January and September" or something like that. Session can mean a term/semester, or an individual morning/afternoon/class, so it's not ambiguous.

Comment: You could say that the class _meets_ twice a week during a four-week session (or once a week for a semester), and you are going to be absent for one _meeting_ or one _day_.

Comment: Schools have courses and courses have classes. The course is offered every third semester. The classes meet twice a week.